# Cordova Hook to modify files in platforms/android/res/values/

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to modify the XML value that's generated in platforms/android/res/values/ to enable a different API key when building with --release

My hook script works under a hooks/before_compile/ however when I run it a second time the modified XML file gets two new lines re-added using the same string name XML.

So to avoid this I've considered deleting the XML file in question from the platforms/android/res/values/ directory during a hooks/before_prepare

If i delete this XML file it never seems to get re-generated now during a cordova build -- when does platforms/android directory contents get regenerated during a build process and how can I get this XML file modified reliably on every build --release ?

Answer (score 0):

Use your hook in before_prepare, so you ensure that your XML is modified before build

Comment: I tried my hook code on a Windows machine (I was using OSX) and it all worked fine. I think the problem is local to my set-up -- but I spent ages and can't explain why to myself.